# Determine a diagonalizable linear map $g:\mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^4}$ knowing an eigenspace and the Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine a diagonalizable linear map $g:\mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^4}$ such that $\ker(g)=\langle(1,-\frac1{2},-\frac1{2},0)\rangle$ and $V_{-2}=\langle (0, 1, 0, 1),(0, 0, −1, 2) \rangle$.

I know there is an eigenspace missing, because the sum of the dimension of those two eigenspace equals $1$.

I would have written down my attempt if I had done something useful, thanks in advance

**Update** (thanks to amd's comment)

I found $e_1=(1,0,0,0)$ to be an eigenvector, given that is linearly independent to the other three eigenvector.

Then I can write a basis of eigenvectors: $$B=\left\{(1,0,0,0),\left(1,-\frac1{2},-\frac1{2},0\right),(0, 1, 0, 1),(0, 0, −1, 2)\right\}$$

Now I can define $M_{BB}(g)$ as the matrix with the eigenvalues in the diagonal, but I don't know the eigenvalue related to $e_1$, shall I put a parameter $k$ and see where $g(e_1)=ke_1$?

Comment: Hint: For the last eigenvector, pick any vector that’s not in the span of the two known eigenspaces.

Comment: Proper notation is $V_{-2}=\langle (0, 1, 0, 1),(0, 0, −1, 2) \rangle,$ not $V_{-2}= < (0, 1, 0, 1),(0, 0, −1, 2) >.$ I edited accordingly.

Comment: As with the free eigenvector, since the last eigenvalue hasn’t been given to you, pick one yourself. Keep in mind that it must be distinct from the other two.

Comment: So if I choose 2 for example,  I've got the vector of a basis and their image, have I done?